# how to allow a worker to run a ffmpeg command on heroku for my python/django app?

Tags: django, heroku, ffmpeg, django-celery, redistogo

I've been stuck trying to figure this out for weeks. I previously asked a similar question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283021/how-to-use-django-celery-rq-worker-to-execute-a-video-filetype-conversion-ffm) but I never got any replies. I really cannot find any good documentation anywhere. All I need to do is use a worker (don't care what worker have django-celery and rq installed) to convert a file to flv when it is uploaded from a form.  I was able to get this done easily locally, but after over a week I haven't been able to get it to work no matter what I have tried. I tried adding a tasks.py file for celery, or a worker.py file for rq, and I have no idea what else (if anything) needs to be done, such as in my settings.py or Procfile. My procfile looks like:

```
web: gunicorn lftv.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
celeryd: celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
worker: python worker.py
```

My requirements.txt showing what I have installed looks like this:

```
Django==1.4.3
Logbook==0.4.1
amqp==1.0.6
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==2.7.3.19
boto==2.6.0
celery==3.0.13
celery-with-redis==3.0
distribute==0.6.31
dj-database-url==0.2.1
django-celery==3.0.11
django-s3-folder-storage==0.1
django-storages==1.1.6
gunicorn==0.16.1
kombu==2.5.4
pil==1.1.7
psycopg2==2.4.5
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2012j
redis==2.7.2
requests==1.1.0
rq==0.3.2
six==1.2.0
times==0.6
```

The only thing relevant in my settings.py are as follows:

```
BROKER_BACKEND = 'django'
BROKER_URL = #For this I copy/pasted the code from my redistogo add-on from heroku. Not sure if correct
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 1800}
```

Without trying to take up too much more space, my tasks.py looks like this:

```
import subprocess

@task
def ffmpeg_conversion(input_file):
    converted_file = subprocess.call(input_file)
    return converted_file
```

I use S3 to store my static and media files, and the upload works (adding uploads to my bucket), however no matter what I try the conversion never will.  Is there a good tutorial for absolute beginners? I followed the heroku redis tutorial, celery docs, rq docs, and whatever else I can find, and got the examples to work, but the worker will not execute the command from my view. For example one of the many things I tried:

```
...
ffmpeg = "ffmpeg -i %s -acodec mp3 -ar 22050 -f flv -s 320x240 %s" % (sourcefile, targetfile)
ffmpegresult = ffmpeg_conversion.delay(ffmpeg)
...
```

or using rq

```
...
q = Queue(connection=conn)
result = q.enqueue(ffmpeg_conversion, ffmpeg)
...
```

I seems like it should be simple, however I am completely self-taught and have never deployed a project whatsoever, and there just doesn't seem to be any good documentation or tutorial available for what I am trying to do.  I can't judge whether I am completely off and completely missing something significant or relatively close to getting this to work.  I really do appreciate any input whatsoever, this is driving me nuts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I seemed to have gotten it working, however now I get the error: ResponseError: max number of clients reached

Comment: not same stack ,but i use ffmeg on heroku, calling a shellscript from java layer and it works fine. Wrap the CLI expression for ffmpeg inside a bash script. Issue a system command from your lang=py running the script, handle stdout in the python and that should work. Then mv the tmp output of the ffmpeg to your persistence api.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar and I don't think you need to create a worker. Why not use a custom build pack, such as https://github.com/integricho/heroku-buildpack-python-ffmpeg.
If you had ffpmeg installed at the OS level, you could then issue video transformation commands from python itself, without the need for a separate worker.

Hope that helps ?